# How to set uploaded image (in category custom field) default location via plugin extension?

Tags: php, media, shopware6, uploading, custom-field-type

Please, how to set uploaded image (in category `custom field`) **default location** via plugin extension?

My plugin extension will create new folder after installation, but when i am uploading my custom image via category custom field, this media is **located** in root directory in media

I need to save it directly, to my created folder - for example: `media/myImageDirectoryForPlugin/`

I know exactly what `ID` has my folder. But i don't know, how link that ID with my Custom Field element for uploading images.

i checked documentation - here: [Own media folder](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/resources/guidelines/testing/store/quality-guidelines-plugins#own-media-folder)

> Customers must create own media folders or use existing ones to upload images.

Unfortunately, this information did not help me in any way :o)

Thank you very much for help.

I tried to set it in my *.php where i am creating my `Folder` and `Custom Field`, but with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't influence the directory path in the filesystem. The folders only exist on the database level, not in the actual filesystem. When you look at `public/media` you will find that the directory tree is generated using hashes and doesn't relate to the folders in the administration.

However, if you still want to use a custom folder for the sake of organization or want to use one of the pre-existing folders, you can. When you create the custom field you can provide additional properties for the component. For the `sw-media-field` component you can use the `defaultFolder` property to define the folder to be used.

When you create a custom folder, you can also provide data for the association to `media_default_folder`. That table has a column `entity` and that's the value you have to provide for the `defaultFolder` property of the custom field, so it will use the associated folder.

```php
// persist the custom folder
$data = [
    'name' => 'my-custom-folder',
    'useParentConfiguration' => false,
    'configuration' => [],
    'defaultFolder' => [
        'associationFields' => [],
        'entity' => 'my_custom_entity',
    ],
];

$this->getContainer()->get('media_folder.repository')
    ->create([$data], Context::createDefaultContext());

// persist the custom field
$data = [
    'name' => 'lorem_ipsum',
    'type' => CustomFieldTypes::TEXT,
    'customFieldSetId' => '...',
    'config' => [
        'componentName' => 'sw-media-field',
        'customFieldPosition' => 1,
        'customFieldType' => CustomFieldTypes::MEDIA,
        'defaultFolder' => 'my_custom_entity',
        'label' => [
            'en-GB' => 'lorem_ipsum',
            'de-DE' => 'lorem_ipsum',
        ],
    ],
];

$this->getContainer()->get('custom_field.repository')
    ->create([$data], Context::createDefaultContext());
```

Comment: Thank you very much !!It helps :-) and it is working :-) 

please, one additional question - now i have an issue, with 'entity' after unninstallation - when i try to install it again - it seems like entity was not unninstalled and i am trying to create new one.  Then i get error. I need to unninstall that as well. 

How can i do it?
'my_custom_entity'


Thanks for help :-)